# Trying to compile an .m file with DeployTool on MAC OSX

Tags: macos, matlab, compiler-construction

I saw there are several discussions on the subject but none of them managed to help me solve mine.

I am trying to compile my Matlab proj. without much success.

I saw this video and pretty much followed it guidances: -> I used 'deploytool'.

When I tried to build the project, I got the below plot. The line has been showed a lot:

```
2013-03-10 14:29:21.014 mcc[39814:4303] This process is attempting to exclude an item from Time Machine by path without administrator privileges. This is not supported.
```

Some discussions stated I need to do write "sudu matlab" somewhere but I do not know where...

Compilation plot:

> ant:
>
> mcc -o Untitled1 -W main:Untitled1 -T link:exe -d /Users/Nimrod/Documents/MATLAB/Temp/Untitled1/src -w enable:specified_file_mismatch -w enable:repeated_file -w enable:switch_ignored -w enable:missing_lib_sentinel -w enable:demo_license -v /Users/Nimrod/Documents/MATLAB/Temp/temp.m
>     2013-03-10 14:29:17.073 mcc[39814:4303] This process is attempting to exclude an item from Time Machine by path without administrator privileges. This is not supported.
>     2013-03-10 14:29:17.075 mcc[39814:4303] This process is attempting to exclude an item from Time Machine by path without administrator privileges. This is not supported.
>
> 2013-03-10 14:29:41.167 mcc[39814:4303] This process is attempting to exclude an item from Time Machine by path without administrator privileges. This is not supported.
>     Compiler version: 4.18 (R2012b)
>     Processing /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/toolbox/matlab/mcc.enc
>     Processing /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/toolbox/shared/spcuilib/mcc.enc
>     Processing include files...
>     2 item(s) added.
>     Processing directories installed with MCR...
>     The file /Users/Nimrod/Documents/MATLAB/Temp/Untitled1/src/mccExcludedFiles.log contains a list of functions excluded from the CTF archive.
>     0 item(s) added.
>     Generating MATLAB path for the compil  ed application...
>     Created 39 path items. 
>     Begin validation of MEX files: Sun Mar 10 14:30:16 2013
>     End validation of MEX files: Sun Mar 10 14:30:16 2013
>     2013-03-10 14:30:16.783 mcc[39814:4303] This process is attempting to exclude an item from Time Machine by path without administrator privileges. This is not supported.
>
> 2013-03-10 14:30:39.015 mcc[39814:4303] This process is attempting to exclude an item from Time Machine by path without administrator privileges. This is not supported.
>     Warning: Adding path "/Users/Nimrod/Documents/MATLAB/Temp" to Compiler path
>     instance.
>     Parsing file "/Users/Nimrod/Documents/MATLAB/Temp/temp.m"
>         (Referenced from: "Compiler Command Line").
>     Parsing file "/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/toolbox/compiler/deploy/deployprint.m"
>         (Referenced from: "Compiler Command Line").
>     Parsing file "/Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/toolbox/compiler/deploy/printdlg.m"
>         (Referenced from: "Compiler Command Line").
>     Deleting 0 temporary MEX authorization files.
>     Generating file "/Users/Nimrod/Documents/MATLAB/Temp/Untitled1/src/readme.txt".
>     Generating file "/Users/Nimrod/Documents/MATLAB/Temp/Untitled1/src/run_Untitled1.sh".
>     copy '/Users/Nimrod/Documents/MATLAB/Temp/Untitled1/src/Untitled1.app' '/Users/Nimrod/Documents/MATLAB/Temp/Untitled1/distrib/Untitled1.app'
>     copy '/Users/Nimrod/Documents/MATLAB/Temp/Untitled1/src/run_Untitled1.sh' '/Users/Nimrod/Documents/MATLAB/Temp/Untitled1/distrib/run_Untitled1.sh'
>     copy '/Users/Nimrod/Documents/MATLAB/Temp/Untitled1/src/readme.txt' '/Users/Nimrod/Documents/MATLAB/Temp/Untitled1/distrib/readme.txt'

When trying to run the app file I get the following crash:

> Process:         prelaunch [39864]
>     Path:            /Users/USER/Documents/*/Untitled1.app/Contents/MacOS/prelaunch
>     Identifier:      Untitled1
>     Version:         1
>     Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
>     Parent Process:  launchd [134]
>     User ID:         501
>
> Date/Time:       2013-03-10 14:37:28.848 +0200
>     OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C2034)
>     Report Version:  10
>
> Interval Since Last Report:          9226 sec
>     Crashes Since Last Report:           5
>     Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   5
>     Anonymous UUID:                      6DB02735-2968-B918-129B-82542E2D0F24
>
> Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
>     Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
>
> Application Specific Information:
>     dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
>
> Dyld Error Message:
>       Library not loaded: @rpath/libmwcpp11compat.dylib
>       Referenced from: /Users/USER/Documents/*/Untitled1.app/Contents/MacOS/prelaunch
>       Reason: image not found
>
> Binary Images:
>            0x100000000 -        0x100000ff7 +Untitled1 (1)  /Users/USER/Documents/*/Untitled1.app/Contents/MacOS/prelaunch
>         0x7fff6205c000 -     0x7fff6209093f  dyld (210.2.3) <36CAA36E-72BC-3E48-96D9-B96A2DF77730> /usr/lib/dyld
>
> Model: MacBookPro9,1, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B08, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.6 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.1f173
>     Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In, 384 MB
>     Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
>     Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533643465238432D50422020
>     Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54333531533643465238432D50422020
>     AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.14)
>     Bluetooth: Version 4.1.2f9 11046, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
>     Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
>     PCI Card: pci11c1,5901, sppci_ieee1394openhci, Thunderbolt@62,0,0
>     PCI Card: Apple 57761-B0, sppci_ethernet, Thunderbolt@61,0,0
>     PCI Card: pci12d8,400e, sppci_usbopenhost, Thunderbolt@60,0,0
>     PCI Card: pci12d8,400e, sppci_usbopenhost, Thunderbolt@60,0,1
>     PCI Card: pci12d8,400f, USB Enhanced Host Controller, Thunderbolt@60,0,2
>     Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS547575A9E384, 750.16 GB
>     Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS31N
>     USB Device: hub_device, 0x8087  (Intel Corporation), 0x0024, 0x1a100000 / 2
>     USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0x1a110000 / 3
>     USB Device: hub_device, 0x8087  (Intel Corporation), 0x0024, 0x1d100000 / 2
>     USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2513, 0x1d180000 / 3
>     USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0x1d181000 / 6
>     USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821d, 0x1d181300 / 7
>     USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0253, 0x1d183000 / 5
>     USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0x1d182000 / 4
>     USB Device: hub_device, apple_vendor_id, 0x9127, 0x40100000 / 2
>     USB Device: Keyboard Hub, apple_vendor_id, 0x1006, 0x40130000 / 6
>     USB Device: Apple Keyboard, apple_vendor_id, 0x0250, 0x40132000 / 7
>     USB Device: Display Audio, apple_vendor_id, 0x1107, 0x40140000 / 5
>     USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Display), apple_vendor_id, 0x1112, 0x40150000 / 4
>     USB Device: Apple Thunderbolt Display, apple_vendor_id, 0x9227, 0x40170000 / 3

Comment: They probably mean "sudo matlab" and this simply means that you need to run MATLAB from the root user. Do you know what I'm talking about?

Comment: Not really. What is Root User or better - How do I run it using the Root User?

Comment: A _root user_ is the superuser (or in short: SU) in a Unix-like OS (like an administrator user in Windows OS). A `sudo` command (that is, "do like su") performs the specified command with root privileges.  To execute something with root privileges, just type `sudo something...`. Certain operations require root privileges, because allowing anyone to perform them puts the system at a security risk. Obviously, to be able to "sudo" something, your user needs to be granted permission on that system.

Comment: Where do I write this line? in Matlab I get the following: **"Undefined function 'sudo' for input arguments of type 'char'."**

Comment: You need to type that in the OS command prompt (not inside MATLAB). Alternatively, you will need to be logged in as the root user, and then you won't have to do any "sudo" stuff.

Comment: Understand. Thanks. I did type that and was asked to produce a password. Once I typed it - I got some error and not when I write `sudo matlab` I get the error `sudo: matlab: command not found`    (All that is even though I am an administrator on my MAC according to the system user preferences)

Comment: This means that there is no "shortcut" for MATLAB called `matlab`. You'll have to manually find where MATLAB is installed, and sudo-run it from there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25912/discussion-between-nimrodb-and-eitant)

Comment: I opened a Terminal and went to ~.Applications/ 
There - there are 2 Matlabs: 
MATLAB folder where the compiler tool was installed 
MATLAB_R2012b.app
where do I need to be to run the sudu and what exactly do I need to write? 
When I went to /Application/ and wrote there sudu MATLAB_R2012b.aap - It also gave the msg that the command not found

Comment: I'm not sure, I've never worked with MATLAB on Mac OS X, so your guess is as good as mine. I suggest you do some more searching on the internet, at least you have a direction now.

Comment: OK - so what I needed to do is: Open Terminal -> write `sudo /Aplications/MATLAB_R2012b/bin/matlab` - that opens the Matlab in admin mode.   Thanks Eitan

Comment: Sounds right. You should post that as an answer and accept it, to help other users solve this problem in the future.